# what is the best method to extract highly correlated vaiables within the given threshold

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have one data frame and pairwise correlation were calculated

```
>>> df1 = pd.read_csv("/home/zebrafish/Desktop/stack.csv")
>>> df1.corr()
           GA        PN        PC       MBP        GR        AP
GA   1.000000  0.070541  0.259937 -0.452661  0.115722  0.268014
PN   0.070541  1.000000  0.512536  0.447831 -0.042238  0.263601
PC   0.259937  0.512536  1.000000  0.331354 -0.254312  0.958877
MBP -0.452661  0.447831  0.331354  1.000000 -0.467683  0.229870
GR   0.115722 -0.042238 -0.254312 -0.467683  1.000000 -0.248777
AP   0.268014  0.263601  0.958877  0.229870 -0.248777  1.000000
>>>
```

now from this correlation matrix how can i list or extract the highly correlated variable in the above case data frame is small so its easy to select the highly correlated variable but when the data set is huge say 4000 X 2000 than how can we do this using python or pandas or numpy.

#### Updated

With the suggested way i was able to get this which is very beautiful , but my confusion  is still there and its not related to programming part its related to theory

```
       level_0 level_1         0
0       GA      GA  1.000000
1       GA      PN  0.070541
2       GA      PC  0.259937
4       GA      GR  0.115722
5       GA      AP  0.268014
6       PN      GA  0.070541
7       PN      PN  1.000000
8       PN      PC  0.512536
9       PN     MBP  0.447831
11      PN      AP  0.263601
12      PC      GA  0.259937
13      PC      PN  0.512536
14      PC      PC  1.000000
15      PC     MBP  0.331354
17      PC      AP  0.958877
19     MBP      PN  0.447831
20     MBP      PC  0.331354
21     MBP     MBP  1.000000
23     MBP      AP  0.229870
24      GR      GA  0.115722
28      GR      GR  1.000000
30      AP      GA  0.268014
31      AP      PN  0.263601
32      AP      PC  0.958877
33      AP     MBP  0.229870
35      AP      AP  1.000000
```

for example in the given peace of result bellow As I want to remove variables which show correlation more than 0.2, we can see   AP is correlated with the remaining three within the given threshold while remaining three are also correlated with AP  (Though, 0.2 is not represent the highly correlated set but chosen just for an example ) so on what basis i can considered a  variable highly correlated or just correlated amongst the four AP, GA, PN and PC.

```
    30      AP      GA  0.268014
    31      AP      PN  0.263601
    32      AP      PC  0.958877
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try this

```
corr_val=0.01
df2 = df1.corr().unstack().reset_index()
df2[df2[0]>corr_val]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i have updated my Question little bit further to clarify a basic concept.